# How to track location of contacts who are sharing their location on google map using google maps api

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoding-api

Google Maps have recently launched Share location feature on Google Maps. I just wanted to know can I use any web service for Google API to track location of the person sharing his location with me on google maps?

Comment: As far as I know the APIs don't offer this functionality at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature request in Google issue tracker

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62938530

You can **add star** to this feature request to show your interest.